# local vs roaming vs temporary windows app data

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to use the correct class for storing data in my windows app.  I used IsolatedStorageSettings on the Windows Phone app, but I need to use the Windows.Storage class in my Windows store App begin written with VS Express 2013

I need the data to remain secure on the device when the app is not in use and don't want it to be saved in the cloud or removed unless the use logs out of the app.  SO it just need to stay secure while the user remains logged in regardless if they are using the app or its in the background or Windows shut it down for memory reasons.

I suspect roaming is not the way to go but which should I use: local or temporary?

Answer (score 5):

OK, after some more research I found this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx

Looks like local app data is the correct method as temporary data can be removed by the device at any time.  Roaming as it says is for data that you want to use across devices that is stored on OneDrive(old Skydrive).

And if someone needs the example code then here is the [link for a simple example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700361.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

local
Data that exists on the current device and is backed up in the cloud.
roaming
Data that exists on all devices on which the user has installed the app.
temporary
Data that could be removed by the system at any time.
localcache
Persistent data that exists only on the current device.